# stop animating ActivityViewIndicator after invalid login

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to iOS programming and currently is playing around with some tutorial found online. I was trying to include an ActivityViewIndicator in the sign in view. When the "Sign In" button is tapped, an ActivityViewIndicator should show up and it show be hidden when sign in is invalid. My problem is where should i put the `self.signInViewIndicator.stopAnimating();` when the sign in is invalid? I have enabled the `Hides When Stopped` option.

```
@IBAction func SignInButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let userUsername = userUsernameTextField.text
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text

    if(userUsername.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty) { return}

    signInViewIndicator.startAnimating()

    // Send user data to server side
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.168.135:8080/userLogin.php")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "username=\(userUsername)&password=\(userPassword)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)


    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        var err: NSError?
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

        if let parseJSON = json {
            var resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String
            println("result: \(resultValue)")

            var isUserSignedIn:Bool = false
            if(resultValue=="Success") {
                isUserSignedIn = true

                // Login is successful
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(isUserSignedIn, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

            } else {
                self.signInViewIndicator.stopAnimating()

                var messageToDisplay:String = parseJSON["message"] as! String!

                if(!isUserSignedIn)
                {
                    messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as! String!
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    // Display alert message with confirmation
                    var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:nil)

                    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                })
            }
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: because it's not working in that area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it rigth, you can never update the UI from a thread other than the main thread, as you was already displaying the alert in the main thread I just had to move your message "`self.signInViewIndicator.stopAnimating()`" to inside that dispatch block:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
     // Display alert message with confirmation
    self.signInViewIndicator.stopAnimating()  
    var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:nil)
    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```